# Specifying database name while using Neo4j-Spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

In the recent version of [Neo4j-Spark connector (4.0.0)](https://neo4j.com/developer/spark/) there is an example in the official documentation which demonstrates reading from Neo4j using spark ([here](https://neo4j.com/developer/spark/reading/)):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

spark.read.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
  .option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687")
  .option("labels", "Person")
  .load()
  .show()
```

Imagine i have several databases running on "bolt://localhost:7687". I wonder how i can specify the database name which i want to read the data from. Does this connector even supports this kind of transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `driver configuration` section https://neo4j.com/developer/spark/configuration/ you can find that the option `database` is used to specify the db to use :

```
spark.read.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
  .option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687")
  .option("database", "mydb")
  .option("labels", "Person")
  .load()
  .show()
```

You can also find the source code for that option here : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/blob/4.0/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/spark/Neo4jOptions.scala#L83